# Minimum normal form of a relation with all prime attributes

Tags: database, relational-database, database-normalization, 3nf, bcnf

If all the attributes of a relation are prime (part of a candidate key), which normal form would it be at least? 1NF, 2NF, 3NF or BCNF.

The question was already solved in slides as BCNF, but I don't understand why BCNF and not 3nf.

Comment: What is your 1 specific researched non-duplicate question? What is the presentation you are stuck in & where/how are you stuck following it? [ask] [Help] [research effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [“help me"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3404097) [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3404097) PS "Minimal" & "at least" are not clear. Do you mean, the maximal/highest NF it must be in? Your language now doesn't say that. A table in a NF is also in all lower NFs. So "minimal" is always unnormalized or, if your higher NFs require a 1NF, that 1NF.

Comment: Please quote the question you are talking about. All attributes prime does not imply BCNF. So, assuming you seek the highest NF it must be in, either you made a mistake interpreting a presentation or the presentation made a mistake. PS A common definition of 3NF says it holds when/iff there are no problematic non-prime attributes. So "If all the attributes of a relation are prime" is the condition satisfied or not?

Comment: Here is an example of a relation where all the attributes are prime but the relation is not in BCNF: `R = (A B C)` with a closure of the dependencies `F = { A -> C, C B -> A)`. All the attributes are primes, since the keys are `(A B)` and `(B C)`, but the dependency `A -> C` violates the BCNF since `A` is not a superkey.